# Присоединительный союз "и"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, союзы

Всегда ли, если предложение начинается союзом "и", этот союз — присоединительный? У Розенталя есть такой пункт на привило пунктуации на стыке союзов:

> 5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом **(в начале предложения, после точки)** и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза:
>      1) как правило, после союза и запятая не ставится: **И когда** Левинсон, выполнив все будничные дела, отдал наконец приказ выступать, — в отряде наступило такое ликование, точно с этим приказом на самом деле кончались всякие мытарства (Ф.); **И хотя** погода значительно улучшилась, опасность засухи не миновала; **И вместо того чтобы** свернуть направо, по ошибке поехали прямо.

### Запятая не будет ставиться даже несмотря на то, что нет второй части союза "то, так, но", и в любых предложениях такого типа?

- И когда мы вышли из дома, погода прояснилась.
- И когда он ещё был далеко, отец увидел его, побежал навстречу.
- И когда апостол закончил проповедь, многие стали спрашивать.

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя (http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=325) все сказано, и сомнения, по-моему, не должны возникать. В Ваших примерах все верно.